# There are three events: $A$ and $B$ and $C$. We know $P(A|B) = P(B|C) = 0.5$. Then $P(A|C)$ should be?

Tags: probability

There are three events: $A$ and $B$ and $C$. We know $P(A|B) = P(B|C) = 0.5$. Then
$P(A|C)$ should be?

Is it $0.5\cdot0.5=0.25$?

The question only provide the above information and the question provide the following choices.

$a. 0.25$

$b. 0.5$

$c. 1$

$d. 0$

$e.$ None of the above is correct

Comment: no it is not 0.25

Comment: What is the reason? So the correct answer is also 0.5?

Answer (score 3):

Why should you be able to tell? You only know how $A$ behaves in the presence of $B$, and how $B$ behaves in the presence of $C$. How could you possibly deduce how $A$ behaves in the presence of $C$, regardless of the presence or absence of $B$?

Examples to show that you can't:

If the events are all independent, then $\mathbb{P}(A \vert C) = \mathbb{P}(A) = \frac{1}{2}$.

If the event $C$ is independent of the others, then $\mathbb{P}(A \vert B) = \mathbb{P}(B) = \frac{1}{2}$, but $\mathbb{P}(A \vert C) = \mathbb{P}(A)$ need not be $\frac{1}{2}$: let $B$ be the event "I get heads on the first of two coins" and $A$ be the event "I get heads on both of the two coins".

Answer (score 0):

You should know at least the probability of the single events to tell. If you'd know you could apply the *Bayes* theorem and solve.